# Sorting and limiting two table queries in php

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to make a feature Sort Hospitals by Ratings of their XXX Service.

I have following tables

```
hospital (hid, name)
sratings (Service ratings) (hospitalId, ratingValue, serviceId)
services  (sid, name
hrating (hid, ratingvalue)
```

Services contain 500+ services.
I also have services "sid" for the xx service

E.g if i chose service Cardiology, It should get first 50 hospitals sorted by srating Service ratings.

What would be the correct query.
A part of query i have already made , that selects all the hospitals and assign them their ratings taken from another table hrating but that's irrelevent now. Just want to sort and get first 50 hospitals rated by service xx

```
SELECT
    hospital.*, 
    (SELECT AVG(hrating.rating_h) 
       FROM hrating 
       WHERE hrating.hid = hospital.hid) as overall_rating
  FROM hospital
```

Comment: Funny thing: YOu're selecting something from `hratings`, but that one isn'T lsited in your table listing...

Comment: @JohannesH. please check the edited code and read carefully what i wrote about that code. its not a part of what i want, that's just appending hotel originial rating not service rating

Comment: So, do you want to sort by the hospital's rating in `hrating`, or by each hospital's rating for the selected service in `sratings`?

Comment: Added `join`tag, as a `JOIN`is what will solve this. DOn'T ahve the time to answer myself though, sorry.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar still, a listing should be complete, otherwise you're just confusing us. Most people will figure otu what's in what table after all, anmes aren't too cryptic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join your tables, then sort the results:

```
SELECT   hospital.*
FROM     hospital
    JOIN sratings ON sratings.hospitalId = hospital.hid
    JOIN services ON services.sid = sratings.serviceId
WHERE    services.name = 'Cardiology'
ORDER BY sratings.ratingValue DESC
LIMIT    50
```

The above query assumes that `(hospitalId, serviceId)` is unique in `sratings` (for example, that it is the primary key of that table).  Otherwise you will have to define how you wish to sort hospitals that have multiple ratings for the same service, for example by average rating:

```
SELECT   hospital.*
FROM     hospital
    JOIN sratings ON sratings.hospitalId = hospital.hid
    JOIN services ON services.sid = sratings.serviceId
WHERE    services.name = 'Cardiology'
GROUP BY hospital.hid
ORDER BY AVG(sratings.ratingValue) DESC
LIMIT    50
```

Comment: Agreed, and just noticed that you didn'T "fix" that subquery and changed it into a join, too, but simple didn't include it in your answer at all. Removed comments, kept rating though, great answer.